# is it possible in php to use try/catch inside eval

Tags: php

hello I am trying to use **try/catch** in php inside the eval () function is possible?.
I try some tests and it doesn't catch the exceptions.

Comment: But still it works https://3v4l.org/2QKoA

Comment: *I try some tests* - could you share these tests and then it may be easier to highlight any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is...

```
eval('

    try {
        throw new Exception;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }

');
```

That code would produce the following output...

```
object(Exception)#1 (7) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(28) "/in/aqFQZ(3) : eval()'d code"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(3)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(9) "/in/aqFQZ"
      ["line"]=>
      int(3)
      ["function"]=>
      string(4) "eval"
    }
  }
  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: hello yes using **throw new Exception** works but when i try to catch mysqli exceptions or division by zero doesnt work. how come?

Comment: I don't know about MySQLi Exception, perhaps you should post a new question to address that issue specifically. However, a `DivisionByZeroError`, which extends `ArithmeticError`, which extends `Error`, which extends `Throwable`, would definitely **not** be caught as `Exception`. You must either catch `DivisionByZeroError` or one of its parent types. Both `Error` and `Exception` are subtypes of `Throwable`, but I'm afraid that doesn't work the other way around. All this is explained in more detail in the [Documentation for Errors in PHP 7](https://www.php.net/language.errors.php7).

Answer (score 0):

ready you have to use 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);